# creating a copy of my app to create a "test server" does not work using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is what I am trying to do: I want to download the code of my existing, and successfully running app (PHP and mySQL) and then upload it again to a different directory. I want to keep the database login the same. So basically I have a "live" code and a "test" code. 
Now, when I go through this process I am getting a blank page when trying to log in as the newly uploaded "test" code. I am really puzzled why this is not working since I have not made any change to the code, I just duplicated it. I guess the blank page is telling me that the test code could not connect to the database. But why? Login details are the same!!
Any idea what I am missing here?

```
require_once("site_constant.php");
require_once("lib/mysql.php");
require_once("lib/function.php");
$DBObject = new db_sql();

$link = $DBObject->db_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_SERVER_USERNAME,DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die('DB not connect');
```

The login details are in site_constant.php, which I have not changed:

```
define('DB_SERVER','xxxx');
define('DB_SERVER_USERNAME','xxxxx');
define('DB_SERVER_PASSWORD','xxxxx');
define('DB_DATABASE','xxxxxx');
define('SITE_URL', 'xxxxxxx');
```

The login function is in lib/mysql.php:

```
function db_connect($server = DB_SERVER, $username = DB_SERVER_USERNAME, $password = DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, $database = DB_DATABASE, $link = 'db_link')
{
    global $$link;
    $$link =mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
    if($$link)
    {
        $$link=mysql_select_db($database);
        if(!$$link)
        {
            $msg="Can't connect from Database";
            $this->db_error($msg,mysql_errno(),mysql_error());
        }     
    }
    else
    {
        $msg="Can't connect from MYSQL";
        $this->db_error($msg,mysql_errno(),mysql_error());
    }
    return $$link;
}
```

Comment: "blank page" is not a good problem description. The reason could be anything. Maybe the site doesn't work from another directory.

Comment: ok, sorry , forgot to mention that the program stops at the $link line. So, it is not connecting to the database. so, are you saying that there might be something defined in the mySQL database that is only allowing access from one location. How could that be done? How can I find this?

Comment: Do you know what `$$link` does?

Comment: Turn error reporting on and see what's wrong.

Comment: $link is use throughout the app as the database login. I guess the $$ could be set to just $. I don't think that is the issue, since it is working like this in the running app.

Comment: are your paths to the includes correct since you moved directories?

Comment: path are all absolute, no relative path, so directories have been copied with the code

Comment: In can not find anything in the mySQL settings that would prevent another app to access the database.

Comment: this is running on a shared server, can I edit the php.ini to turn on error reporting?